# sprite Kit rotating node in landscape distorts image

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am trying to continuously rotate my SKSpriteNode. When I try to rotate the node in the portrait orientation with the following code it works great:

```
SKSpriteNode *player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];
player.position = CGPointMake( 200, 200);
player.name = @"player";
SKAction *rotation = [SKAction rotateByAngle: 2 * M_PI duration:10];
SKAction* continuousRotation = [SKAction repeatActionForever:rotation];
[player runAction: continuousRotation];
[self addChild: player];
```

However, when I try to do this in the landscape orientation (which I ultimately want it to be in) the image gets distorted as it rotates. Is there any way to fix this problem? Or would I only be able to use the portrait orientation for this?

Comment: Maybe your problem is not in sprite rotation, check that your scene is resized correctly when changed device orientation.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't doing that before but now that I did it works great.